# MVC not throwing validation error for 'XXX@YYY' style email address but still causing invalid model state

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

For some reason Im getting no validation error for input in an email field formed in the following patter 'xxx@yyy' basically missing the .domain part. It is causing a modelstate error though just not triggering the validation message.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class SubscriptionForm
{
    [Required, EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Heres my simple action:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Subscribe(SubscriptionForm form)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        return Json(new {OK= false});

    var sub = new Subscription();
    sub.Email = form.Email;
    Database.Session.Save(sub);
    return Json(new {OK = true});
}
```

Heres the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("subscribe", "subscriptions", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-inline", id = "subscribe-form"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ....
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new {@class = "form-control", type = "email", placeholder = "your@email.here"})
    <input type="submit" id="subscribe-btn" value="Subscribe Now!" class="btn btn-large btn-success"/>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
}
```

A blank email throws the message so does any other invalid email input like 'abcd' 'abcd@.c' etc, its only xxx@yyy that seems to have the issue.

Anyone have any idea whats causing this? I've been googling for the past hour to no avail.

**EDIT**

Heres the JS for the Ajax submit
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
$('#subscribe-form').on("submit", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);

    console.log($form);

    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    var $url = $form.attr("action");
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(response);
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: " +
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    // Prevent default posting of form

});
```

Comment: Put a break point at `if(!ModelState.IsValid)` inspect the `ModelState` and look at the errors, you should be able to see what is throwing the error.

Comment: It is throwing the exact same "Invalid Email Address" error as any of the other invalid email inputs, but no message shows on the view for some reason? I'm completely at a loss

Comment: Try removing `type = "email"` - that's for generating the browsers HTML5 email control which may be interfering with jquery unobtrusive validation

Comment: And the fact your method is returning JSON suggest your submitting the form using ajax, in which case show the relevant code

Comment: Removed the 'type = email' still no luck. Added the JS to the question

Comment: MVC has thrown an error because it is inside the `modelstate` but as you are ajax the post the results returned are inside of your JSON. You will need to use the return value from your JSON to output the errors.

Comment: But if I put in jibberish to the field, or nothing at all it validates with the correct message? Why would this incorrect format be different?

Comment: Doe this still occur if you do a normal submit? (i.e. comment out the script)

Comment: yeah, its actually happening all throughout the project on any email field. Ajax or normal submit. Im starting to think it may be a bug in the unobtrusive validation lib?

Comment: There is no bug. And when I copy your code into a project and enter `'"xxx@yyy"` it displays the error message and the form is not submitted (doing a normal submit). There must be something else in you code causing the issue.

Comment: That is so strange do you have any idea where I should start looking?